# Filling Dojox.grid.DataGrid with JSON Data

Tags: dojo

I have JSON Data in this format :

```
var jsonData = [{date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06},{date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06},{date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06}];
```

How can i print this data inside my Dojox.grid.DataGrid

```
<body class=" claro ">
        <span dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="store1" url="data.json">
        </span>
        <table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="store1" 
       style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="150px" >
                        Title of Movie
                    </th>
                    <th width="150px">
                        Year
                    </th>
                    <th width="150px" >
                        Producer
                    </th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
        </table>

    </body>
```

Comment: I don't understand this question.. please clear it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remeber that ItemFileReadStore (all types of stores actually) need data in a specific format. You are telling me that you have a jsonData variable:

```
var jsonData = [{date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06},{date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06},{date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06}];
```

This is not the format ItemFileReadStore wants. ItemFileReadStore wants an object with at least two properties: identifier and items. So change your data to:

```
var jsonData = {identifier: "id", 
                items: [
                  {id: 1, date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06},
                  {id: 2, date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06},
                  {id: 3, date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06}
                ]};
```

As you can see, it's now an object with the required properties. The identifier property tells the store to use a property named "id" to uniquely distinguish the items. Your objects didn't have a unique property, so I added the id property on all items. You probably have some other property you can use.

Next, since you have your data in a variable, why are you telling your ItemFileReadStore to get data from a URL called data.json? Instead, do:

```
<span dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="store1" data="jsonData"></span>
```

Lastly, your Grid itself. The table headers need to correspond to properties on the items in the store. You have, for example date, open and high, so use the `field` attribute on each `th`:

```
<table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="store1" 
   style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="150px" field="date">Title of Movie</th>
            <th width="150px" field="open">Year</th>
            <th width="150px" field="high">Producer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I added "height: 500px" to the table, but that may not be necessary for you.